# How do I repeat certain items in an array based on matched values in another array?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, arrays

I've been trying for a couple weeks to figure this out, but I'm totally stumped.

I have an array that represents `item_id`'s: `[2, 4, 5, 6, 2, 3]`.

I have another array that represents how many times each item shows up: `[1, 1, 3, 3, 2, 5]` .

I want to check that all items have been completed so I want to create an array that has the total number of `item_id`'s in it. I will compare that array against a completed items array that will be created as the user completes each item, so, from the example above, the array I'm trying to create is:

```
[2, 4, 5, 5, 5, 6, 6, 6, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3]
```

---

EDIT:

I'm building a workout app, so a user has a workout which has many exercises. Each exercise has one or more sets associated with it. The user completes an exercise when he has completed every set for that exercise, and completes a workout when he completes all exercises for that workout. In this question I'm trying to determine when a user has finished a workout.

EDIT 2:

I wish I could award multiple right answers! Thanks everyone!

Comment: Would you mind telling us a bit more about the specific domain? What exactly is being completed?

Comment: Why are your item_id's repeating in the first array? How can we distinguish one two from the other? This is for the case when there are 0, 2's and the arrays might look like this [2,2,2,3,4,5] [2,0,1,1,1,1] [2,3,4,5]?

Comment: @depa Sure! I was just trying to keep things simple. I updated the question with more information about what I'm doing with the app.

Comment: @Sanchit there are situations where a workout could have an exercise more than once. An exercise will never have 0 sets, so that situation will never exist.

Comment: Since no two numbers repeat in array1. Convert the 3rd array into a form of the 2nd array then compare with the 2nd array.

Comment: Why are you using arrays? Can't you use a rails association?

Comment: @LarryMcKenzie I am using associations for adding exercises to workouts, but in this case I'm just trying to determine when a user has completed a workout, so I figured I need a list of items, and a list of completed items, and when those lists match, I have a completed something.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
item_ids = [2, 4, 5, 6, 2, 3]
counts = [1, 1, 3, 3, 2, 5]
item_ids.zip(counts).map{|item_id,count| [item_id]*count}.flatten
 => [2, 4, 5, 5, 5, 6, 6, 6, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3]
```

What's going on here? Let's look at it step by step.

`zip` takes two arrays and "zips" them together element-by-element. I did this to create an array of item_id, count pairs.

```
item_ids.zip(counts)
 => [[2, 1], [4, 1], [5, 3], [6, 3], [2, 2], [3, 5]]
```

`map` takes each element of an array and executes a block. In this case, I'm using the `*` operator to expand each item_id into an array of `count` elements.

```
[1]*3 => [1, 1, 1]
[[2, 1], [4, 1], [5, 3], [6, 3], [2, 2], [3, 5]].map{|item_id,count| [item_id]*count}
 => [[2], [4], [5, 5, 5], [6, 6, 6], [2, 2], [3, 3, 3, 3, 3]]
```

Finally, `flatten` takes an array of arrays and "flattens" it down into a 1-dimensional array.

```
[[2], [4], [5, 5, 5], [6, 6, 6], [2, 2], [3, 3, 3, 3, 3]].flatten
 => [2, 4, 5, 5, 5, 6, 6, 6, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3]
```

Comment: Just to point out to the OP, this answer is essentially the same as @Speransky Danil's answer, but his was submitted first.

Comment: Thanks @theTinMan. I awarded this answer because it does such a great job explaining why it's done this way. I wish I could award both answers.

Comment: Thanks! I also just realized this could be shortened by using `flat_map` instead of `map{..}.flatten`. But this way is a bit easier to explain. :)

Answer (score 5):

Ok, @sameera207 suggested one way, then I will suggest another way (functional style):

```
arr1 = [2, 4, 5, 6, 2, 3]
arr2 = [1, 1, 3, 3, 2, 5]

arr1.zip(arr2).flat_map { |n1, n2| [n1] * n2 }
```

Comment: Rather than use `map{ ... }.flatten` try `flat_map`.

Answer (score 1):

This is a one way of doing it:

```
a = [2,4,5,6,2,3]
b = [1,1,3,3,2,5]
c = []

a.each.with_index do |index, i|
  b[index].to_i.times {c << i }
end
p c
```

Comment: Why do you use `b[index].to_i`? Why not `b[index]` since `b` only contains integers to begin with? And why `each.with_index` instead of `each_with_index`?

Answer (score 1):

```
ids = [2, 4, 5, 6, 2, 3]
repeats = [1, 1, 3, 3, 2, 5]

result = []
ids.count.times do |j|
  repeats[j].times { result << ids[j] }
end
```